# Remove checked checkboxes using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to remove my checked checkboxes using

```
$(".gone").removeAttr('checked');
```

If you scroll to the bottom and click `+ Add new Line` it will append another `<tr>`. What I'm trying to do is remove a `<tr>` if the checkbox is checked. So if I check multiple boxes it will remove all the `<tr>'s` that are checked. What am I doing wrong? Why aren't the checkboxes being removed with the above code?

This is my live example: https://jsfiddle.net/nwqmvo36/17/

****UPDATE****

Tried using

```
 $(document).on("click", "div.rem", function() {
     $(this).closest("tr:checked").remove();
 });
```

This did not work either. I'm trying different solutions, I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use event delegation. This will make sense if you want to add for example event listeners to elements that append after that the DOM has been loaded. In your situation you can add an event listener to the element with class `.gone` and then find all checked `checkboxes` and remove the parent `tr`. You can use the following code:

```
$(".gone").on("click", function() {
    $('.no-more-tables') // element container
        .find(":checkbox:checked") // return checked checkbox(es)
        .closest('tr') // return first parent tr
        .remove(); // remove them
});
```

Also a [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/nwqmvo36/20/)

**References**

[:checkbox](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)

[closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[find](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

[:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Comment: Thank you for explaining the process.

Comment: Can I prevent this from removing the header?

Comment: @unlvt You can ask a different question as this one fulfill your OP.

Answer (score 1):

Here I updated a code for you. You didn't call the class of the checkboxes

```js
$(".checkAll").change(function () {
    $(".selectall").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    $(".gone").removeAttr('checked');
});

$('.vv div:first-child').on('click', function(){
 $("tbody").append('<tr class="remove"><td><input class="chk" type="checkbox" class="selectall" /></td><td><span class="hdv dsp">Product</span><span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span></td><td><span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 1</span><span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span></td><td><span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 2</span><span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span></td><td><span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 3</span><span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span></td><td><span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 4</span><span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span></td><td><span class="hdv dsp">Quantity</span><span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">1</span></td><td><span class="hdv dsp">Price</span><span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">$00.00</span></td></tr>');
});


$('.gone').click(function() {
  $('input:checked.chk').each(function(idx, item){
  var row = $(item).parents(".remove");
    if (row != null)
     row.remove();
  });
  });
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    
    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
 .no-more-tables table, 
 .no-more-tables thead, 
 .no-more-tables tbody, 
 .no-more-tables th, 
 .no-more-tables td, 
 .no-more-tables tr { 
  display: block; 
 }
 
 /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
 .no-more-tables thead tr { 
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
 }
 .hdv {
   width: 46%;
   padding: 5px;
   display: inline-block;
  }
  .dsp {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
 .no-more-tables tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
 
 .no-more-tables td { 
  /* Behave  like a "row" */
    width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;  
  white-space: normal;
  text-align:left;
 }
 

 /*
 Label the data
 */
}
.cf {
  width:100%;
}
.cf > tr > th {
  text-align: left;
}
.cf > tbody > tr > td {
  height: 25px;
}
.newvariation > td > input:focus {
  outline:0px !important;
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
.vv > div {
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) {
 .dsp {
   visibility: hidden;
   display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="no-more-tables">
            <table class="table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">
          <thead class="cf">
           <tr>
            <th class="c1"><input type="checkbox" class="checkAll"/></th>
            <th class="c2">Product</th>
            <th class="c3" contenteditable="true">Variation 1</th>
            <th class="c4" contenteditable="true">Variation 2</th>
            <th class="c5" contenteditable="true">Variation 3</th>
            <th class="c6" contenteditable="true">Variation 4</th>
            <th class="c7">Quantity</th>
            <th class="c8">Price</th>
           </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectall" /></td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Product</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">iPhone 7 Plus</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 1</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">64GB</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 2</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">Matte Black</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 3</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 4</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Quantity</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">3</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Price</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">$964.36</span>
                </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectall" /></td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Product</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">iPhone 7 Plus</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 1</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">64GB</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 2</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">Matte Black</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 3</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 4</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Quantity</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">3</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Price</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">$964.36</span>
                </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectall" /></td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Product</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">iPhone 7 Plus</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 1</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">64GB</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 2</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">Matte Black</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 3</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 4</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Quantity</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">3</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Price</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">$964.36</span>
                </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectall" /></td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Product</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">iPhone 7 Plus</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 1</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">64GB</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 2</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">Matte Black</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 3</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 4</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Quantity</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">3</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Price</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">$964.36</span>
                </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectall" /></td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Product</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">iPhone 7 Plus</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 1</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">64GB</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 2</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">Matte Black</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 3</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 4</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Quantity</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">3</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Price</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">$964.36</span>
                </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectall" /></td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Product</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">iPhone 7 Plus</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 1</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">64GB</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 2</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">Matte Black</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 3</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 4</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Quantity</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">3</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Price</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">$964.36</span>
                </td>
           </tr>
           <tr class="removeAttr">
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="selectall" /></td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Product</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">iPhone 7 Plus</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 1</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">64GB</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 2</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">Matte Black</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 3</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp" contenteditable="true">Variation 4</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">--</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Quantity</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">3</span>
                </td>
                <td>
              <span class="hdv dsp">Price</span>
                  <span class="hdv" contenteditable="true">$964.36</span>
                </td>
           </tr>

          </tbody>
         </table>
        </div>
<div class="vv">
  <div>+ Add new Line</div>
  <div class="gone">- Remove selected</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is only removing the check from the box. Not the actual `<tr>`

Comment: What do you mean by `I've attached the button to the code but when I click on the button it does not remove the checked boxes. What am I doing wrong?` then? So that's not what you want?

Comment: If you scroll to the bottom and click `+ Add new Line` it will append another `<tr>`. What I'm trying to do is remove a `<tr>` if the checkbox is checked. So if I check multiple boxes it will remove all the `<tr>'s` that are checked.

Comment: @unlvt okay I get it. Then please edit your question.

Comment: any proposed solution?

Comment: @unlvt sorry2 I was busy. I will it again after lunch.

Comment: @Fiido93 yes cuz i only focus on the appended data  :)

Comment: Alex has the shortest way of method on doing what the `Poster` want.

Answer (score 0):

You're removing the checked attribute, not the object, you need to use the [checked selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

try this:

```
$(".gone:checked").remove();
```